# twig if statement with multiple conditions [symfony2]

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have an entity named `verified` in my table `user`. I would like if verified is `null` to show this [you can upload your application], if verified `=2` to show this [your application is in process], if verified `=3` your application has been verified.

but for now if verified `=3` is showing the message of verified `=2.`

This is what i have done:

```
 {% if entity.verified is empty %}

<p>
you can upload your application
</p>

{% elseif entity.verified|length !=2 %}

<p>
your application is in process
</p>

{% elseif entity.verified|length !=3 %}

<p>
your application has been verified
</p>
 {% endif %}
```

**User.php**

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="verified", type="decimal", options={"default" : 0}, nullable=true)
 */
protected $verified;

/**
 * Set verified
 *
 * @param string $verified
 * @return User
 */
public function setVerified($verified)
{
    $this->verified = $verified;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get verified
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getVerified()
{
    return $this->verified;
}
```

Comment: the answer from Matteo would be correct if you were comparing with an EQUALS, it is currently using an NOT. Personally I would do this logic in the controller and set a virtual attribute on the entity or make a custom getter on the model that does the logic (do not have to map this to a column) that has the text you require, then your twig can just spit that out

Comment: Why are you using the not equal (!=) sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the length filter (the scope of that filter is for count the element of an array, collection etc), so try simple:

```
{% if entity.verified is empty %}    
    <p>you can upload your application</p>
{% elseif entity.verified == 2 %}
    <p>your application is in process</p>
{% elseif entity.verified == 3 %}
    <p>your application has been verified</p>
{% endif %}
```

And invert the condition.

Hope this help

Comment: i removed the lenght filter , but still having the same issue. if I set verified to 3 it should show your application has been verified but it showing this your application is in process.

Comment: You are still using an not equals comparison, instead use an equals comparison

Comment: @Rooneyl I changed `!=` to `==` and it works nicely.Thank you so much :)